# Camera preview is looking layed down instead of straight when I minimise the height of camera

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

In my application, I am scanning barcode using device camera. For that I need the camera preview of limited size that is `match-parent` by width and `200 dp` by height. but when I minimize the height of camera with `200 dp`, the picture preview is looking lay down not straight as shown in below screenshot. I want to make the preview straight. I have set `mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90)` but it doesn't work.

**Screenshot:**

**Observed**
[image]

**Expected**[image]

Pleas Help.

Comment: Share screenshot for better understanding of your issue.

Comment: Yes @SweetWisherツ is right. You should share screenshot too.

Comment: hav added screenshot.. plz check

Comment: Are you using any library for Barcode??

Comment: yes zbar lib using for barcode scanning

Comment: then there is no such issue with it...I have used it and also customized the view.

Comment: Do you want it in potrait mode??

Comment: yes in potrait mode.. preview image doesnt look straight.. that is the problem. if i increase the height it looks proper. but when i fixed the height with 200dp, preview shows picture layed downward.

Comment: share the preview too (expected and observed both)

Comment: see the differences..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62456/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-girl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue by setting camera preview height-width with SurfaceView height-width. may be it help someone.